# rails 4 RSpec test validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

It looks like you used to be able to write RSpec tests with the following syntax

```
it { should validate_presence_of :privacy }
```

However I'm receiving the following error

```
error undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Review:0x007fd819c1bdc8>
```

I can write tests the following way but the above syntax is much simpler

```
it "should require privacy" do 
   expect(FactoryGirl.build(:review, privacy: "")).to_not be_valid
end
```

Is there a 1 liner to test validations using Rails 4.2 and rspec-rails 3.0? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Make sure you have the `shoulda` gem in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Which version of shoulda-matchers are you using? If it is 3.0 check [this post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/shoulda-matchers-3-0). They changed a few things in the new version.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is:

```
it { is_expected.not_to be_valid }
```

You can read all about it at [Relish](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax)

Edited to add clarification:

This assumes the subject is either explicitly stated, like

```
subject{ FactoryGirl.build(:wiget) }
```

or is able to be inferred.